# Prove that $F(1) + F(3) + F(5) + ... + F(2n-1) = F(2n)$

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

(These are Fibonacci numbers; $f(1) = 0$, $f(3) = 1$, $f(5) = 5$, etc.) I'm having trouble proving this with induction, I know how to prove the base case and present the induction hypothesis but I'm unfamiliar with proving series such as this. Any help would be great. :)

Comment: Why do you use two different notations for the numbers? Either $f(n)$ of $F(n)$. Then numbers are $0,1,1,2,3,5,\ldots$. So if $f(5)=5$ then $f(1)=1, f(3)=2$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume this is true for $ n $. Now, let's consider the sum:

$$ F_1 + F_3 + \dots + F_{2n-1} + F_{2n+1}$$

By induction hypothesis, the sum without the last piece is equal to $ F_{2n} $ and therefore it's all equal to:

$$ F_{2n} + F_{2n+1} $$

And it's the definition of $ F_{2n+2} $, so we proved that our induction hypothesis implies the equality:

$$ F_1 + F_3 + \dots + F_{2n-1} + F_{2n+1} = F_{2n+2}$$

Which finishes the proof

Comment: and you start with which $n$? For $n=1$ you get $0=f(1)=f(2)=?$

Comment: The question was about the induction step, so what I covered was the case $n>2$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** If you can use the that the sequence of Fibonacci numbers is defined by the [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) $$F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)$$ then you can prove it by induction, since $$\begin{align*}F(2(n+1))&=F(2n+2)\\&=F(2n+1)+F(2n)\\&=F(2n+1)+\underbrace{F(2n-1)+\ldots+F(5)+F(3)+F(1)}_{=F(2n) \text{ by induction hypothesis}}\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

The following is formally not correct because it uses the "$\cdots$" symbol but it gives some insight. The proof can be formalized using induction. This was already done by @Jytug.
$$\begin{eqnarray}
F(1) + F(3) + F(5) + \cdots + F(2n-1)&= \\
0+\left(F(1) + F(3) + F(5) + \cdots  + F(2n-1)\right) &= \\
F(0)+\left(F(1) + F(3) + F(5) + \cdots  + F(2n-1)\right)&=\\
\left(F(0)+F(1)\right) +\left( F(3) + F(5) + \cdots + F(2n-1)\right)&=\\
F(2)+\left( F(3) + F(5) + \cdots  + F(2n-1)\right)&=\\
\left(F(2)+F(3)\right) + \left( F(5) + \cdots  + F(2n-1)\right)&=\\
F(4) + \left( F(5) + \cdots  + F(2n-1)\right)&=\\
\cdots&=\\
F(2n-2)+F(2n-1)&=\\
F(2n)&
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using [Binet's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression):

$F(n) = a \alpha^n + b \beta^n$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$, and $\alpha,\beta$ the roots of $X^2=X+1$. (Their precise value is not really important here.)

Now,
$
\alpha^1 + \alpha^3 + \cdots + \alpha^{2n-1}
=\alpha(1+\alpha^2 + \alpha^4 + \cdots + \alpha^{2n-2})
=\alpha\dfrac{\alpha^{2n}-1}{\alpha^2-1}
=\alpha^{2n}-1
$
because $\alpha=\alpha^2-1$.

Analogously,
$
\beta^1 + \beta ^3 + \cdots + \beta ^{2n-1}
=\beta ^{2n}-1
$.

Therefore,
$
F(1) + F(3) + F(5) + \cdots + F(2n-1) = a(\alpha^{2n}-1)+b(\beta ^{2n}-1)=F(2n)-a-b
$.

Finally, $a+b=F(0)=0$.

Comment: I usually prefer *not* to use Binet's formula if I can avoid it, just for elegance's sake. But this problem screamed for a solution with geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

Since $F(2n)-F(2n-2)=F(2n-1)$, this reduces to a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series):
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^nF(2k-1)
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(F(2k)-F(2k-2))\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^nF(2k)-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}F(2k)\\
&=F(2n)-F(0)\\[9pt]
&=F(2n)
\end{align}
$$