# Fibonacci summation proof using matrices?

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers

I have a standard proof for the theorem:

$$\sum_{}^n  f_1+f_3+f_5+...+f_{2n-1} = f_{2n}$$

$$f_i$$ refers to the Fibonacci numbers for future reference.

It involves setting p(k) as p(k+1) and proving it through weak induction, it has been graded by my professor and is correct.

However, I have recently came across the fibonacci matrix formulation from here:

[How to prove Fibonacci sequence with matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784710/how-to-prove-fibonacci-sequence-with-matrices)

I am curious how I would go about solving this theorem with matrices.

I have tried using the product operator: $$\Pi$$

but I am not experienced enough to correctly formulate it so that they equal each other, for example:

$$\Pi_{i=1}^n  \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^{2n-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^{2n}$$

Using the product operator may be completely pointless, but I honestly just don't know since I have never really used them before.

Any idea on how the original theorem is shown in matrices?

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Yes, $$f_i$$ refers to the fibonacci numbers, i'll edit that in.  Thank you.

Comment: There is no $i$ in the summands of your sum $\sum_i$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That is a completely different Fibonacci identity.

Comment: Ooops, will be corrected soon ([this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035861/prove-that-f1-f3-f5-f2n-1-f2n) is the right identity., but not yet with matrices).

Comment: One nice setup for the matrix proof is to begin by noting that 
$$
\pmatrix{f_1\\f_0} + \pmatrix{f_3\\f_2} + \cdots + \pmatrix{f_{2n-1}\\f_{2n-2}} = \\
\pmatrix{1\\0} + F^2 \pmatrix{1\\0} + \cdots + F^{2n-2}\pmatrix{1\\0} $$
where $F = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}$

Comment: I have never seen that put that way before @Omnomnomnom, thank you and it is starting to make more sense on how to go about it.

Answer (score 6):

Letting $F=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$, so $F^2=F+I$, then the finite geometric series formula gives
$$
I + F^2 + F^4 + \dots + F^{2n-2} = (F^{2n}-I)(F^2-I)^{-1} = (F^{2n}-I)F^{-1}=F^{2n-1}-F^{-1}.
$$
Since $F^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}$, conclude by examining the upper left entry of the equation 
$$
I + F^2 + F^4 + \dots + F^{2n-2} = F^{2n-1}-F^{-1}.
$$
and recalling that $F^n=\begin{bmatrix}F_{n+1}&F_{n}\\F_{n}&F_{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Also, $F^{-1}=F-I$.